# How to increase the heap size of WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile in eclipse. My webapp has been giving `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and thus I need to increase the heap size.

As [this](https://blakboard.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/how-to-configure-heap-size-for-websphere-application-server/) and [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321221) post suggested I changed the `server.xml`, by adding `jvmEntries` tag (It was not previously there):

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
        the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"  id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

    <jvmEntries initialHeapSize="1024" maximumHeapSize="2048" />
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
    <webApplication id="app" location="app.war"
        name="app" />
</server>
```

But eclipse shows it as an invalid tag, with following error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'jvmEntries'. One of '{include, variable, trustAssociation,
>   applicationMonitor, application, classloading, basicRegistry,
>   bundleRepository, osgiApplication, authentication, authCache,
>   jaasLoginModule,   jaasLoginContextEntry, cdiContainer, channelfw,
>   tcpOptions, library, collectiveMember, hostAuthInfo,
>   managedExecutorService, connectionManager, contextService,
>   distributedMap, enterpriseApplication, webApplication, httpDispatcher,
>   mimeTypes, httpEncoding,   virtualHost, httpOptions,
>   httpAccessLogging, httpEndpoint, authData, dataSource, jdbcDriver,
>   jndiEntry, jpa, jspEngine, fileset, executor, featureManager, config,
>   customLdapFilterProperties, edirectoryLdapFilterProperties,
>   domino50LdapFilterProperties,   netscapeLdapFilterProperties,
>   ldapRegistry, securewayLdapFilterProperties,
>   iplanetLdapFilterProperties, idsLdapFilterProperties,
>   activedLdapFilterProperties, logging, ltpa, ejbContainer, monitor,
>   oauthProvider, oauth-roles, remoteFileAccess, administrator-role,
>   quickStartSecurity, pluginConfiguration, webContainer, httpSession,
>   httpSessionDatabase, sslDefault, keyStore, ssl, sslOptions,
>   timedOperation, transaction, webAppSecurity, federatedRepository,
>   zosLogging, authorization-roles}' is expected.

How should I increase the heap size then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct way to do it is to create `jvm.options` file in the server directory with the following content e.g.:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Check this link [Customizing the Liberty profile environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-2-0&lang=en)

In Eclipse, in the `Servers` view you can right-click the server, and select `New > Server Environment File > jvm.options`

Comment: Thanks for sharing perfect solution. I almost about to lose my life

Answer (score 0):

The Liberty profile is a bit different than the regular WebSphere profile.  You will need to configure a jvm.options file per these instructions:

[IBM Setting generic JVM arguments in the WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21596474)

[Customizing the Liberty profile environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html?lang=en)